# Activity not listed in Activity Chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing a photo editor app but facing a problem launching the editor activity (`EditorActivity`) with implicit `intents`.

A `intent filter` for `EditorActivity` has been set to:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
<data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

I use this code to start the `EditorActivity`:

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
editIntent.setDataAndType(null, "image/*");
startActivity(editIntent);
```

But the `EditorActivity` is not listed in the activity chooser.

What confuses me more is that if I add these three lines into `MainActivity`'s intent filter, the `MainActivity` IS listed in the activity chooser.

The **manifest file** for this app is listed below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".EditorActivity"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be like this

```
<activity android:name=".EditorActivity"
          android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Give a shot, Hope this helps to solve your prob.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had added `<intent-filter>` to the code before. The manifest file in the question has been corrected now. The real reason is that I redirected the build folder in gradle and it did not resync the new builder folder.